Expo build for iOS disable push notifications per project
I used push notifications for the app that was built before with Expo, and now I am working on a new app that doesn't require push notifications.
I saw in identities for the new app it has enabled push notifications, I disabled it there but still when doing eas build -p ios --profile production it always does:
✔ Synced capabilities: Enabled: Push Notifications

And then when I submit the app I get an email from Apple:

Although delivery was successful, you may want to correct the following issues in your next delivery. Once you've corrected the issues, upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears
to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app
signature's entitlements do not include the 'aps-environment'
entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
Distribution provisioning profile that includes the 'aps-environment'
entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment
entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is
intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications
in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the
entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.

This is app.json:
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "App",
    "slug": "app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "ios": {
      "buildNumber": "7",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.company.app"
    },
    "android": {
      "versionCode": 7,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.company.app"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-asset",
        {
          "assets": ["./assets/logo.png"]
        }
      ]
    ],
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "{uuid}"
      }
    },
    "owner": "company",
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "appVersion"
    },
    "updates": {
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/{uuid}"
    }
  }
}


Expo version: 51.0.8.
How can I enable/disable this in Expo per project?

Did you find any solution I'm facing the same issue

@KoumaIbrahim still no, I am discussing it on discord and will write an answer here when/if it is fixed.

Add this to your app.json
 "ios": {
    "entitlements": {
    "aps-environment": "development"
  }
 }

This will remove the "ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement..." warning.

have you find the solution for this?
I fixed it with the code example in the SDK 51 change-log: https://expo.dev/changelog/2024/05-07-sdk-51#deprecations-renamings-and-removals
The last point: Notifications entitlement is no longer always added to iOS projects during prebuild
The notifications entitlement is probably required, otherwise I cannot tell why it is automatically checked in the App ID identifiers: image
